# Upper and lower dimmensions in schematics

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, schematics

**What is the difference between upper and lower dimmensions in schematics?**

So far I have assumed that those are simply maximum and minimum values specified by the tolerance. Is my assumption correct?

**Edit 1:**

There is also a statement bellow the datasheet that tolerances are +/- 0.15mm which is inaccurate in the case of 3.60/3.20 (or 2.90/2.50).

A relevant schematics here:

[image]

Comment: @Armandas thank you, yes, the answer is really similar to the one you provided but please see my edit.

Comment: BTW, that isn't a schematic, that's a mechanical drawing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are right.
Sometimes manufacturers specify min/max and sometimes just average value and state tolerance.

Comment: There is also a statement bellow the datasheet that tolerances are +/- 0.15mm which is inaccurate in the case of 3.60/3.20 . Am I missing something here?

Comment: 0.15 mm applies when the error is NOT specified otherwise, e.g. in the pin spacing (1.80) on the left.